# Palindrome and as well as anagrammatism?

Tags: python-3.x

How can we create a program that checks if the input we give(for example: EXAMPLE) has the same length and the same letters with (XAMPLEE)?

Comment: Please provide us with the code you wrote and tried, and be more specific about the problem you face with this code.

Answer (score 0):

this is efficient python code for it

```
NO_OF_CHARS = 256
def areAnagram(str1, str2):

    # Create two count arrays and initialize all values as 0
    count1 = [0] * NO_OF_CHARS
    count2 = [0] * NO_OF_CHARS

    # For each character in input strings, increment count
    # in the corresponding count array
    for i in str1:
        count1[ord(i)]+=1

    for i in str2:
        count2[ord(i)]+=1

    # If both strings are of different length. Removing this
    # condition will make the program fail for strings like
    # "aaca" and "aca"
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return 0

    # Compare count arrays
    for i in xrange(NO_OF_CHARS):
        if count1[i] != count2[i]:
            return 0

    return 1
str1 = "EXAMPLE"
str2 = "XAMPLEE"
if areAnagram(str1, str2):
    print "The two strings are anagram of each other"
else:
    print "The two strings are not anagram of each other"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import array

word1 = "EXAMPLE"
word2 = "XAMPLEE"
letters = array.array('i',(0,)*26)

# Count letters of word1
for c in word1:
  charIndex = ord(c) - ord('A')
  letters[charIndex] = letters[charIndex]+1

# Count letters of word2 and substract them from word1 count
for c in word2:
  charIndex = ord(c) - ord('A')
  letters[charIndex] = letters[charIndex]-1

# letters contains only 0 if words are the same
if letters.count(0) < 26:
  print("Words are different")
else:
  print("Words are anagrams")
```